# How to parametrize log in setup fixture with data from JSON & command line both

Tags: python, python-3.x, parameter-passing, pytest, fixtures

I am setting up some basic UI tests in pytest for my web application. Each functionality test in this app requires user to log in first. I would like to create a setup fixture that will open a browser (what browser, what server - depends on command line arguments), and then log in using data from JSON file (no hardcoding values). I would not like to base my test cases on log-in test case (which has multiple sets of data), I would like to use a separate fixture.

I succesfully created a setup that opens desired browser & uses desired server, but I have no idea how to parametrize the fixture, to also use data from JSON.

So, if I wanted to use a function in my setup fixture that logs me in, and requires parameters like login & password:

```
login_page = LoginPage(driver)
login_page.log_me_in(login, password)
```

how should I add it to my setup fixture?

This is my conftest.py setup:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def setup(request, browser, server_instance):
    if browser is None:
        browser = "iexplorer"

    if server_instance is None:
        server_instance = "test"

    driver = WebdriverFactory(browser, server_instance).webdriver_instance()

    if request.cls is not None:
        request.cls.driver = driver

    yield driver
    driver.quit()
```

As well as adding parameters from command line:

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--browser", help="choose test browser: iexplorer, 
    firefox, chrome")
    parser.addoption("--server_instance", help="choose test server instance: 
    test, user")


@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def browser(request):
   return request.config.getoption("--browser")


@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def server_instance(request):
    return request.config.getoption("--server_instance")
```

I tried using pytest_generate_tests, but I do not fully understand how and on what basis the parameters are later added to the fixture.

Or maybe I should add another fixture that uses setup fixture, and logs me in? Still, how to pass the parameters from file?

Please, point me in the right direction! Thank you!